# Activating virtual environment doesn't work from npm command

Tags: python, node.js, shell, npm, pip

In my `package.json` I have a script to activate my python virtual environment (my project uses both Python and Nodejs). I basically want to activate my virtual environment from npm.

```
"scripts": {
    "babel-node": "babel-node --stage 0 --ignore='foo|bar|baz'",
    "test": "export NODE_ENV='test'; ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha --compilers js:babel/register server/test/index.js",
    "dev": "./node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js --exec npm run babel-node -- server/index.js",
    "activate": "source ./venv/bin/activate",

    "import": "python scraper -g -i -db caltrain_test && python ./scraper -g -i",
    "start": "node ./server",
    "docs": "cp README.md docs/index.md && ./node_modules/docco/bin/docco --layout=linear ./docs/index.md"
},
```

If I activate my virtual environment form the command line directly, it works:

```
jorgesilvajetter at Jorges-MacBook-Pro-2 in ~/Sites/2015/caltrain-api on master [!?$]
$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv) // This means that it worked!
```

If, however I run the same command from npm, it doesn't work:

```
jorgesilvajetter at Jorges-MacBook-Pro-2 in ~/Sites/2015/caltrain-api on master [!?$]
$ npm run activate

> caltrain-api@0.0.3 activate /Users/jorgesilvajetter/Sites/2015/caltrain-api
> source ./venv/bin/activate
```

Is it possible to activate my virtual environment through an npm command? It seems I'm misunderstanding something about how virtual environments work or how npm executes scripts. Perhaps, it's running the script in another session/tab?

Comment: did you actually solve this problem? I am running into the same issue. I wish I could just use npm for everything

Comment: Seems like it's not possible :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts, "Scripts are run by passing the line as a script argument to sh." So, though you're using `source`, it is in a new subshell.

And just a heads up: npm adds `./node_modules/.bin` to the `PATH` for npm scripts, so in npm scripts you can just write e.g `"nodemon"` instead of `".node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js"` or `".node_modules/.bin/nodemon`. npm knows to populate `./node_modules/.bin` with the correct scripts because package authors specify the `"bin"` property in their `package.json`'s.

Comment: Cool, that make sense. Yeah, I know the second part. I guess I just like that notation because it makes it clear that `nodemon` is a dependency of the project and doesn't need to be globally installed, but you can disagree with me if you want.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your request I did the following :

I am using  `Django`, and want to start the backend server to use it with `Reactjs`.

## Step 1 :

Create a file on your Django project next to your `manage.py` i.e: `activate.py` with the following code

```
import subprocess

# Path to your python in the env
pythonBinary = "./env/Scripts/python"

# Path to your manage.py file
managePy = "./manage.py"

subprocess.Popen([pythonBinary, managePy, "runserver"])
```

## Step 2 :

Your scripts in your `package.json` should look like this

```
...

"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "activate": "cd /path/to/your/django/project && python activate.py"
  },

...
```

it worked for me, I hope it does for you !

Have a good day

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `package.json`:

```
{
 "scripts": {
    "predev": "bash -c 'source ./.venv/bin/activate'",
    "dev": "nodemon --exec \"python3\" src/main.py"
  },
}
```

my `nodemon.json` file looks like:

```
{
  "watch": ["."],
  "ext": ".py",
  "exec": "python3 ./src/main.py"
}
```

I think it only works for linux